# XML without a root element still valid?

Tags: sql-server, xml, split

I found this very nice way to split strings:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100)='a,b,c';

--This is the "normal" way
WITH SplitXml(x) AS
(SELECT CAST('<root><x>' + REPLACE(@x,',','</x><x>') + '</x></root>' AS XML))
SELECT SplitXml.x, a.b.value('.','varchar(1)')
FROM SplitXml
CROSS APPLY SplitXml.x.nodes('/root/x') AS a(b);
```

Then I found the same approach without "root" and I thought this would not work, but it does...

```
--Now the same without "root"
--This leads to invalid XML, but works without problems
WITH SplitXml(x) AS
(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@x,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
SELECT SplitXml.x, a.b.value('.','varchar(1)')
FROM SplitXml
CROSS APPLY SplitXml.x.nodes('/x') AS a(b)
```

Is the XML in SplitXml.x valid or invalid? Does an XML always need a root-singleton?